# Whats the difference between setAttribute & setAttributeNode?

Tags: php, dom

I'm playing around with PHP's [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) at the moment. As the question states, what are the differences between these two methods (other than needing to pas a DOMAttr to setAttributeNode) and in what situations should each be used?

Comment: Shouldn't the question be "*In what situations do I ever need AttributeNodes?*" - the difference between the two methods is clear.

Comment: That is the difference. What do you expect? :?

Comment: These comments seem a little pedantic. It's clear that the OP is asking what the practical difference is and when one would elect to use one method over the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I recall, there's not a lot in it. The main difference, other than the one you've identified, is `setAttributeNode` cannot be used to simultaneously set a value for the attribute, only its name.

In effect, it's a means of preparing an attribute, off the DOM, for insertion at a later point.

`setAttribute` is a quicker means of doing this; it allows the stipulation of both the name and value.

Comment: "`setAttributeNode` cannot be used to simultaneously set a value for the attribute, only its name." ... I guess this sounds wrong. `var atr=document.createAttribute("class"); // Create a "class" attribute`, `atr.value = "democlass"; // Set the value`, `ELEMENT.setAttributeNode(atr); // (simultaneously) Add the "class" attribute with value="democlass" to the ELEMENT`

Comment: He is correct. He said setAttributeNode cannot be used to set a name and value for the ATTRIBUTE.

Basically with setAttributeNode you can delay assigning a value for the attribute to a later time. In case you ever need that functionality I guess.

Comment: It's funny because this answer absolutely applies to JavaScript and I was actually searching for JS and found this question and answer :)